# Specialist for dates?

Tags: science

Does some branch of history as a science specialized in dates (in the sense of time, not romantic involvement)? Or is it a task too small and too important for not being everybody's business?

Comment: You mean [chronology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology)?

Comment: Dates or dating?

Comment: @LennartRegebro: calling it dating is still ambiguous.

Comment: @Michael: yep. I was missing this word.

Answer (score 3):

[Chronology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology) is the science of arranging events in their order of occurrence in time. Perhaps you are interested in the variety of [calendars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar) used over time and in different cultures.

It is worth noting that time determination is not a trivial task in computing, despite a standard being developed for it: [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This is due to issues such as cultural differences, calendar changes, [intercalcary months, weeks, days or seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercalation_%28timekeeping%29), daylight savings changes and time zones.

Comment: +1 - _It is worth noting that time determination is not a trivial task in computing_ : Check out [**Calendrica**](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachum/calendar-book/third-edition/CIIT.html) - good stuff.